# missing values (NA) causing TRUE/FALSE error

Tags: r, na, vegan

Running an analysis in RStudio, R version 3.0.1, Ubuntu 12.04. I am correlating environmental factors (envW) to an analysis (MDSnsj) using the function envfit from the vegan package 2.0-8. My environmental dataset (envW) has many missing values. I get the following error message when I run this simple command. I have tried putting text 'NA' in the missing spots but I get the same error message.

```
envfit(MDSnsj, envW, perm=999, na.rm=TRUE)->MDSnsef
>Error in if (any(x < 0, na.rm = na.rm)) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Can anyone explain to me what the error message means? AND .... Does anyone have any ideas how I can fix this? Thank you in advance

a guess at what is requested

> traceback()
>       MDSnsef<-envfit(MDSnsj, envW, perm=999, na.rm=TRUE)
>       debugging in: envfit(MDSnsj, envW, perm = 999, na.rm = TRUE)
>       debug: {
>           UseMethod("envfit")
>       }

Comment: We need the data you ran the command with. Or a toy example that can reproduce this error. Thanks.

Comment: The error message means that in the `if` condition there are no values of `x` that are not `NA`. I don't know anything about `envfit`, but possibly there are "groups" in your data that consist entirely of `NA` values. Maybe you can exclude these "groups" from analysis.

Comment: Btw, the version number of RStudio (the IDE) is not often relevant. The version numbers of R and of the package could be more interesting.

Comment: The model-fitting function `envfit` is basically choking somewhere. It could be because you have NAs in your data, or not. Just because the error message mentions missing values doesn't mean these things are necessarily related.

Comment: The output from `traceback()` would also be useful.

Comment: not a great way to solve but when I attempted to reproduce error with smaller envW dataset it didn't always error out.....I was able then to narrow th ecause down to a few columns of data. i removed them as non-esential and th eerror did not reoccur

Comment: thank you for all help, i still learnt many things, especially correct language and trouble shooting

Comment: You need to run `MDSnsef <- envfit(MDSnsj, envW, perm=999, na.rm=TRUE)` *and then* as soon as you get the **error**, run `traceback()`. Copy what it printed and add it to your question. Note that `envfit` has argument `na.rm = FALSE` and hence it would have bailed out already with an informative error message if `NA`s were an issue (or at least that is how it is intended). To debug, you need `debugonce(vegan:::envfit.default)` as the method doing the work in this case is not exported from the NAMESPACE.